# Git http.cookiefile configuration option not working

Tags: git, curl, github

The configuration option `git config --global http.cookiefile /<absolute path>/my_cookiefile` does not seem to have any effect on git. Having the following cookiefile :

> Set-Cookie:my_cookie=my_value; Path=/; Domain=.github.com

The file perfectly work using directly :

> $curl  -v --cookie my_cookiefile https://github.com/my_url
>
> GET my_url HTTP/1.1
>   Host: github.com
>   Cookie: my_cookie=my_value

But it has no effect with git (same curl output but no cookie header):

> $export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 && git clone https://github.com/my_url
>
> GET my_url HTTP/1.1
>   Host: github.com

git version 1.7.1

Any idea of what could be wrong ?

Comment: did you give a relative or absolute path to git config?

Comment: @Chronial absolute path

Comment: Is there any line with `http.cookiefile` in the local `repository/.git/config` ?

Comment: It works for me, with git version 2.29.2. My cookie file is in Netscape format, rather than a plain header value, but according to the documentation both should work. Maybe this question should be closed now?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding it manually. First navigate to your `.git` directory and `cat` the `config` file. If it doesn't include `cookiefile` set to something (be it `=` following a `=`), you could try setting it manually like so: open the `config` file in the editor of your choice, and paste the following to the bottom of that file, replacing `<absolute_path_to_file>` with the absolute path to your cookie file (omit the `[http]` if that section is already defined; if so add the setting under the existing section):

```
[http]
    cookiefile = <absolute_path_to_file>
```

Save, exit and try again.